# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while fetching data from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am fetching data from the server and getting the data successfully as you can see in the screenshot, I also checked my code. my code is working properly when I take data manually, but I don't know why I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

[image]

**Orders.js file:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Toolbar from '../../components/Navigation/Toolbar/Toolbar';
import Order from '../../components/Order/Order';
import axios from 'axios';

class Orders extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            orders:[]
        }

        this.componentDidMount=(event) =>{

            axios.get('https://reactjs-burger-builder-2607.firebaseio.com/orders.json')
              .then(response =>{
                console.log(response.data)
                let updatedOrders=[];
                for(let key in response.data)
                {
                    updatedOrders.push(response.data[key]);
                }
                this.setState({
                    orders:[].concat(updatedOrders),
                });
            })
        }     
}

  render() { 

      console.log(this.state.orders);

      let allOrders='loading..'; 
      if(this.state.orders){
          allOrders= <Order orders={this.state.orders}/>
      }

    return (
        <div>
        <Toolbar/>
        {allOrders}
        </div>    
    );
  }
}

export default Orders;
```

**Order.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Order.css';

const Order =(props) =>{

    console.log(props.orders);

    return(  
        <div>
         {props.orders.map(order =>
          <div className={classes.order} key={Math.random()}>
              <span>name: {order.name} </span><br/>
              <span>contact: {order.contact} </span><br/>
              <span>address: {order.address} </span><br/>
              <span>Price: {order.price} Rs </span><br/>
              <p><span>ingredients: </span>
              {order.ingredients.map(ingredient =>
                 <span key={Math.random()} className={classes.ingredients}>{ingredient.name} ({ingredient.qty}) </span>
               )}
              </p>
         </div>
        )}

        </div>
    );
}

export default Order;
```

Comment: FYI, you don't have to concat the array in setState, because you are creating a new array above with let updatedOrders=[]; anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all orders have ingredients (order: -LlR57Tm3bO2xX31ywFq). This is why it fails for certain orders. You have to check first if the order has ingredients.

```
return(  
    <div>
     {props.orders.map(order =>
      <div className={classes.order} key={Math.random()}>
          <span>name: {order.name} </span><br/>
          <span>contact: {order.contact} </span><br/>
          <span>address: {order.address} </span><br/>
          <span>Price: {order.price} Rs </span><br/>
          <p><span>ingredients: </span>
          {order.ingredients ? order.ingredients.map(ingredient =>
             <span key={Math.random()} className={classes.ingredients}>{ingredient.name} ({ingredient.qty}) </span>
           ) : 'No ingredients'}
          </p>
     </div>
    )}

    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it worked. but I didn't get how only this order doesn't have ingredients, all the orders have ingredients except this.

Comment: That I don't know :) You have to ask the guys who host the endpoint. If that worked for you, you should mark this answer as accepted. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there is an order without ingredients. Just check if ingredients are there before mapping:

```
{Array.isArray(order.ingredients) && order.ingredients.map(ingredient =>
  <span key={Math.random()} className={classes.ingredients}>{ingredient.name} ({ingredient.qty}) </span>
)}
```

By the way, your code contains a couple of problems:

1. Do not use `Math.random()` as list element key, this is the worst possible input to key element (it's better to leave key alone). Refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

```
let updatedOrders=[];
for(let key in response.data)
{
  updatedOrders.push(response.data[key]);
}
this.setState({
  orders:[].concat(updatedOrders),
});
```

2. This part of code makes no sense. Especially naming `updatedOffers` and `[].concat(updatedOrders)`.
3. Why do you assign a value to `componentDidMount` in constructor rather than default method declaration in ES6? You mix ES5 and ES6.

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked. but I didn't get how only this order doesn't have ingredients, all the orders have ingredients except this. Thanks for the above 3 points also :).

Answer (score 0):

map is  one of the Array methods and because you're array object(orders) is undefined this type error occurred.
also you make several mistake. I refactoring orders component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Toolbar from "../../components/Navigation/Toolbar/Toolbar";
import Order from "../../components/Order/Order";
import axios from "axios";

class Orders extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      orders: []
    };
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  getData() {
    return axios
      .get("https://reactjs-burger-builder-2607.firebaseio.com/orders.json")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          orders: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  //this lifecycle method called when component mount
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.orders);

    const RenderOrders = () => {
      if (this.state.orders.length) {
        return <Orders orders={this.state.orders} />;
      } else {
        return <p>...loading</p>;
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Toolbar />
        <RenderOrders />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Orders;
```

Comment: The array object orders is not undefined. The ingredients array in one of the orders is undefined.

Comment: @Domino987 yes one of that is undefined.

Comment: Because you said, that the orders array is undefined.